# Simple proof that this sequence converges [verification]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

This is a relatively simple problem. I'm just making sure I have the right idea here. I'd like to prove that the sequence $\displaystyle a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$ converges. My proof is:

We conjecture that $a_n$ converges to 1. Thus, we must show that, for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N(\epsilon)$.

From that inequality, I do some algebra and find that: $~~\displaystyle n > \frac{1}{\epsilon^3}$, so, if we choose $\displaystyle N(\epsilon) > \frac{1}{\epsilon^3}$, we've shown that the sequence converges to 1.

Is this correct?

Comment: I believe you are saying "series" when you mean to be saying "sequence".

Comment: @DavidH I believe you're correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this won't go unanswered:
Yes, you're correct. If $n>1/\epsilon^{3}$ then $n^{-1/3}<\epsilon$, for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks